# Confused about gravitational length contraction

Tags: general-relativity

From the Schwarzschild metric it seems to me that gravity does not cause length contraction but rather length extension.

$$ ds = \left(1-\frac{r}{r_s}\right)^{-1/2}dr > dr $$

I must be making a foolish mistake here.

Comment: Is it that the outside observer measures 1 units of length less than the observer in the gravitational field? For example, observer in the gravitational field measures 1 meter, then for the outside observer this will be measured less than 1 meter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in one sense, incorrect in another sense and in a third sense it's a meaningless question.

You are correct that if we let down a measuring tape to measure the distance between two shells of radii $r$ and $r+1$ then the distance measured by the tape will be greater than $1$m.

But consider the perspective of the observer at infinity. Far from the black hole the distance measured between the two shells of radii $r$ and $r+1$m is $1$m. So if I take my $1$m measuring rod it fits neatly between the two shells. Now suppose I give you my measuring rod and you take it close to the event horizon. The rod is now shorter than the distance between two shells $r$ and $r+1$m so from my perspective the rod has shrunk i.e. been contracted.

The rod hasn't really contracted of course. Rather the rod has stayed the same length and the distance between the shells $r$m and $r+1$ has increased. But from the perspective of the observer at infinity it looks as if the rod has been contracted.

And this brings us on to my last point, which is that whether the rod has contracted or not is really a meaningless question. It's meaningless because the Schwarzschild $r$ coordinate is not a measure of radial distance and therefore trying to interpret the length of the rod as measured by changes in $r$ isn't a meaningful thing to do.

It's very tempting to think of the $r$ coordinate as a radial distance but it isn't. It is defined as the circumference of a circle centred on the black hole divided by $2\pi$. In flat space this has the simple interpretation of a radial distance because obviously the circumference is $2\pi r$. However if we naively attempt to calculate the proper length from the centre of the black hole to a distance $r$ it always comes out infinite for any $r \gt 0$.

Comment: This may be a tad bit too late, but thank you for clearing this up. For the measuring rod inside the gravitational field 1 m will be measured, but the outside observer will say that the rod is less than 1 m cause of the factor greater than 1 in front of it. Is that correct?

Comment: @JordyMolenaar the problem is that the observer at infinity is interpreting the distance between two concentric shells of radius $r$ and $r+1$ as being one metre, but it isn't because it's greater than one metre. So the observer will say the 1m rule must be less than 1m long.

Comment: The observer at infinity interprets the distance between the two shells of r and r+1 as 1 m, but an observer holding a measure rod of length 1m(that was taken from infinity and measured 1m there) at the radius r will be seen as less than 1 m by the outside observer. Its tricky to visualize because we don't really see it in our lives 

Comment: @JordyMolenaar: *tricky to visualize* pretty much sums up GR :-)

Comment: Well at least Im convinced by the equations.  $dl=a dr$, since $a>1$, dr must be smaller. dr is measurement from outside observer. So from an outside observer length appears to be contracted close to the horizon.