Stretching of space as distance to massive body like black hole decreases, true or false?
This question is about the stretching/elongation/expansion of a measuring rod in a gravitational field according to general relativity. It's not about the spagettification of something falling into the black hole, and not about the expansion of space and the universe causing red shift of photons proportional to distance/time traveled through space, and it's not about the curvature of space (I think).
I have seen some people say that yes, the measuring rod is actually elongated because space itself expands in proportion to the strength of the gravitational field, and in addition to this effect you also have time dilation.
I have also seen other people say that no, that stretching is not real and is just another way of saying that time dilation causes the clock to run slower in proportion to the strength of the gravitational field. So the only effect is time dilation.

Is the measuring rod elongated or not according to GR?
Is the elongation dependent on direction in space relative to the hole?
Is there a physical explanation for the elongation?
Is there an algebraic expression (avoiding tensor math) for the amount of elongation relative to the distance from the event horizon so that I can see the magnitude of it?


None of this would happen in static Minkowski space so it's clearly about curvature. To answer these questions, we mostly just have to be careful about definitions.

If something which looks like a meter stick at infinity is brought near a black hole, an observer who lives there would say it has been contracted. I.e. at radius $r_0$,
\begin{align}
\Delta L &= \int_{r_0}^{r_0 + L} \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1 - 2m/r}}. \quad (1)
\end{align}
The result of this fits in a couple lines but it's definitely greater than $L$ for $r_0 > 2m$. So a stick of proper length $L$ no longer reaches from $r_0$ to $r_0 + L$. Note that the integrand just uses the $dr^2$ coefficient in
\begin{align}
ds^2 = -(1 - 2m/r) dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1 - 2m/r} + r^2 d\Omega^2. \quad (2)
\end{align}
This definitely depends on the orientation of the rod. If it's placed tangent to the event horizon at radial co-ordinate $r_0$, we can use the isotropic co-ordinates
\begin{align}
ds^2 &= -\left ( \frac{1 - m/2R}{1 + m/2R} \right )^2 dt^2 + (1 + m/2R)^4 (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2) \quad (3) \\
R &\equiv \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}.
\end{align}
Now at $(y, z) = (r_0, 0)$, we can do
\begin{align}
\Delta L = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} \left ( 1 + \frac{m}{2\sqrt{x^2 + r_0^2}} \right )^2 dx \quad(4)
\end{align}
which is different.
The difference in length between observers close to and far away from the event horizon is inevitable once you agree that the spacetime curvature is given by (2) and (3). This follows from Einstein's equation but, as always, only some people count this as a physical explanation.
Algebraic expressions can be found by evaluating (1) and (4). And then they can be plotted for various reasonable parameters to give a sense of how great this effect is.


I'm rather sceptical of such an analysis because it should go the other way: the rest length of an object should be the result of the integral with unknown limits, such that you work backward to find these limits of integration, and then that supposedly corresponds to what an observer at infinity would seem to think that the new lengths are.

So, at 1 in your answer, the meter stick has a fixed length independent of the gravitational field. When the meter stick then is brought from large distance deep into the gravitational field it seems to have contracted, but that is just because space itself has expanded as an effect of the stronger gravitational field. Right?

I agree with both of those statements. I said that when you integrate from $r_0$ to $r_0 + L$, you get something greater than $L$. But of course this means that the new length (integration limit which gives $L$) is smaller, agreeing with contraction. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/369486/confused-about-gravitational-length-contraction
